# Postgres partitioned table join with non partition table

Tags: postgresql-9.4, database-partitioning

I have two table one is partitioned and other is not. Tables definition are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE partition.statuschanges
(
  statuschangeid serial NOT NULL,
  username character varying(32) NOT NULL,
  taskid integer NOT NULL,
  status character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  reason character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT pk_statuschanges_statuschangeid PRIMARY KEY (statuschangeid),
  CONSTRAINT fk_statuschanges_task FOREIGN KEY (taskid) REFERENCES partition.tasks (taskid) MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)

CREATE INDEX idx_statuschanges_taskid  ON partition.statuschanges  USING btree (taskid);

CREATE TABLE partition.tasks
(
  taskid serial NOT NULL,
  status character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  claimedby character varying(255),
  populateddate timestamp with time zone,
  CONSTRAINT pk_tasks_taskid PRIMARY KEY (taskid)
)

CREATE TABLE partition.tasks_active
(
  CONSTRAINT pk_tasks_taskid_active PRIMARY KEY (taskid)
  CONSTRAINT tasks_active_check1 CHECK (status::text <> ALL (ARRAY['Done'::character varying, 'Remove'::character varying]::text[]))
) INHERITS (partition.tasks)

CREATE TABLE partition.tasks_closed
(
  CONSTRAINT pk_tasks_taskid_closed PRIMARY KEY (taskid),
  CONSTRAINT tasks_active_check1 CHECK (status::text = ANY (ARRAY['Done'::character varying, 'Remove'::character varying]::text[]))
) INHERITS (partition.tasks)
```

when I am trying to join the tables then Index created for StatusChange table is ignored by the query planner.

```
SELECT t.taskid FROM partition.tasks t, partition.statuschanges s where t.status = 'Done' and s.taskid = t.taskid
```

[image]

How can I utilize the indexes in join?

Comment: For only 20 rows, a Seq Scan is the most efficient thing to do

Comment: The execution plan is better posted as formatted text (as you did with the SQL), not as a screenshot. The output of `explain (analyze, buffers)` might be more helpful as well. If you really need partitioning, I would strongly recommend to upgrade to Postgres 12 which has many substantial improvements to partitioning and how they are used during a query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : What if there are thousands of records. 
Then a Seq Scan is bound to be slow. Shouldn't Postgres use the `idx_statuschanges_taskid`?

Comment: If there are thousand of rows or more then Postgres will like switch to an index scan if that is more efficient than a Seq Scan - the plan chosen depends on the statistics of the table and they depend on the number of rows and the values in the columns.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : wasn't aware of that...